# Select up to last 2 values per grouping and display them side by side

Tags: sql, oracle, group

A table is periodically updated (incrementing load_id). How to select

- **for each** value in column **name**
- **the last** two value in column **count**
- where **last** is given by **max(load_id) per day**
- and put them **side by side**?

**Input**

```
name,day,count,load_id
John,10,9,14
John,9,5,12
John,9,7,13
John,8,5,12
John,8,2,11
Paul,9,0,12
Paul,9,1,13
Paul,7,1,11
Paul,7,9,10
Mark,7,10,11
Mark,7,11,10
Ned,7,0,10
```

Step 1 - Last record per each day

```
name,day,count
John,10,9
John,9,7
John,8,5
Paul,9,1
Paul,7,1
Mark,7,10
Ned,7,0
```

**Output**

```
name,last_day_last_count,prev_day_last_count
John,9,7
Paul,1,1
Mark,10,NULL
Ned,0,NULL
```

**Attempt**

```
WITH RankedData AS (
  SELECT
    name,
    day,
    count,
    load_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, day ORDER BY load_id DESC) AS rn
  FROM test
)

SELECT *
FROM RankedData
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY name, day DESC
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EG_8sNGn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate grouping by `name` and `day` to find the `MAX`imum `load_id` and the corresponding `count` and then use `ROW_NUMBER` to number the rows by `DESC`ending `load_id` for each person and finally `PIVOT` to get the latest 2 values as columns, rather than rows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         MAX(count) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY load_id) AS count,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY MAX(load_id) DESC) AS rn
  FROM   test
  GROUP BY name, day
)
PIVOT(
  MAX(count) FOR rn IN (
    1 AS last_day_count,
    2 AS prev_day_count
  )
)
```

Or else use `ROW_NUMBER` in two passes:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         count,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY load_id DESC)
           AS rn_by_person
  FROM   (
    SELECT name,
           load_id,
           count,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, day ORDER BY load_id DESC)
             AS rn_by_day
    FROM   test
  )
  WHERE  rn_by_day = 1
)
PIVOT(
  MAX(count) FOR rn_by_person IN (
    1 AS last_day_count,
    2 AS prev_day_count
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

| NAME | LAST_DAY_COUNT | PREV_DAY_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 9 | 7 |
| Mark | 10 | *null* |
| Ned | 0 | *null* |
| Paul | 1 | 1 |

---

To get the corresponding `load_id`s as well:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         MAX(count) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY load_id) AS count,
         MAX(load_id) AS load_id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY MAX(load_id) DESC) AS rn
  FROM   test
  GROUP BY name, day
)
PIVOT(
  MAX(count) AS count,
  MAX(load_id) AS load_id
  FOR rn IN (
    1 AS last_day,
    2 AS prev_day
  )
)
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         load_id,
         count,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY load_id DESC)
           AS rn_by_person
  FROM   (
    SELECT name,
           load_id,
           count,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, day ORDER BY load_id DESC)
             AS rn_by_day
    FROM   test
  )
  WHERE  rn_by_day = 1
)
PIVOT(
  MAX(count) AS count,
  MAX(load_id) AS load_id
  FOR rn_by_person IN (
    1 AS last_day,
    2 AS prev_day
  )
)
```

Which both output:

| NAME | LAST_DAY_COUNT | LAST_DAY_LOAD_ID | PREV_DAY_COUNT | PREV_DAY_LOAD_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 9 | 14 | 7 | 13 |
| Mark | 10 | 11 | *null* | *null* |
| Ned | 0 | 10 | *null* | *null* |
| Paul | 1 | 13 | 1 | 11 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r3giiQlm)

Comment: Thanks. What if you want to display not only count side by side but also e.g. load_id for each side? Can above be adjusted easily?

Comment: @learning_python_self Yes, [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gDwIH_yP)